# Mockito + Dexmaker on Android

Tags: android, mockito, dexmaker

I am trying to use Mockito in my Android project.
I have found very nice tutorial that deals with it: http://www.paulbutcher.com/2012/05/mockito-on-android-step-by-step/

Basically it uses new version of Mockito + Dexmaker and everything works as expected.
However, when I try to mock some Android specific object i.e:

```
Context context = mock(Context.class);
```

I receive this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    dexcache == null (and no default could be found; 
    consider setting the 'dexmaker.dexcache' system property)
at com.google.dexmaker.DexMaker.generateAndLoad(DexMaker.java:359)
at com.google.dexmaker.stock.ProxyBuilder.buildProxyClass(ProxyBuilder.java:252)
at com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker.createMock(DexmakerMockMaker.java:54)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: If you don't build your APKs using gradle see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290795/attempt-to-mockito-mock-any-class-generates-exceptionininitializererror/41350001#41350001 for more information

Answer (score 33, accepted):

From @rjath's comment of @MrChaz's answer, this works better for me:

```
System.setProperty(
    "dexmaker.dexcache",
    getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
```

I put it in my `setUp()` method.

Answer (score 10):

I've managed to piece together a fix that seems to be working for me.
To the manifest I added read and write external storage.
To the test I added `System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", "/sdcard");` to the test.
To the emulator image I added an SD card.

I believe this works because by default mockito tries to use the apps cache directory but I never run an activity so I suspect the directory is never created by the OS

Comment: You can also call the following as given here - http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=2 ...     'getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getCacheDir();'

Answer (score 8):

So the problem is with Dexmaker not being able to find the cache path on Android >= 4.3 as other people mentioned and as described in [this dexmaker issue](http://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=2).

I went with implementing the workaround in a custom instrumented test runner instead of in every test (or their superclass) `setUp()`, because it feels a bit less hacky (it really is in only one place - and not inherited in every subclass) and more flexible.
For the sake of documentation these are the necessary changes to do this:

```
public class CustomInstrumentationTestRunner extends InstrumentationTestRunner {

    @Override public void onCreate (final Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);

        // temporary workaround for an incompatibility in current dexmaker (1.1) implementation and Android >= 4.3
        // cf. https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=2 for details
        System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getTargetContext().getCacheDir().toString());
    }
}
```

And set up your project (or test project) to use this class as the instrumented test runner in its `AndroidManifest.xml` when building with ant:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="my.package.CustomInstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="my.target.package" />
```

or its `build.gradle` when building with gradle:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // ...
        testInstrumentationRunner 'my.package.CustomInstrumentationTestRunner'
    }
    // ...
}
```

If you have other `instrumentation` entries, you can switch between them either [on the command line](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html) or select one in your IDE running configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue for an Android Library project but NOT for the application project! Setting the System property "dexmaker.dexcache" as mentioned above worked around the issue.
I'm running Android 4.3 Nexus 4 device, building with 19.0.3 tools, target api 19,
my dependencies:

```
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0"
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0"
```

Comment: I just realized I have experienced the same thing you mentioned (problems in library but not application), I just didn't know why it was happening at the time.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the *dexmaker* project has moved from [Google Code](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/) to [GitHub](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker).

In [the maven central repository](https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.dexmaker%22%20AND%20a%3A%22dexmaker%22) there are versions 1.1 and 1.2 published in March 2014 and December 2014.

I've verified this "dexcache == null" issue still exists through version 1.2 - but only on certain devices.  For example, a Galaxy S5 with Android 5.0 has the problem, and a Galaxy S4 with Android 4.4.2 does not.

I cloned the GitHub repository ([last commit March 12th 2015 - ca74669](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker/commit/ca74669)), and ran locally, and the problem has been fixed (there are also commits in the history that back this up).  So once there is a 1.3 release, hopefully this problem is gone for good!

Anyone else wanting to run a local copy of 1.3-SNAPSHOT, here's how I did that (on a Mac, but other platforms should work too, you'll need *mvn*, *adb*, and *dx* on *PATH*):

1. `git clone`https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker.git
2. `cd dexmaker`
3. `mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=true`
4. `cp -R ~/.m2/repository/com/google/dexmaker $ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/com/google`
5. Then change version in `app/build.gradle`: `androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.3-SNAPSHOT'`

   - Or `pom.xml` if using maven to build, or overwrite your `libs/dexmaker.jar` with `~/.m2/repository/com/google/dexmaker/dexmaker/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dexmaker-1.3-SNAPSHOT.jar` if you are using eclipse/ant

Also, FYI, the [original issue report](https://code.google.com/p/dexmaker/issues/detail?id=2) for the same issue on Google Code as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the mockito core as a dependency instead. Then, that error will not happen and you won't need a workaround.

```
dependencies {
   ... 
   testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I observed this issue when did manipulations with resources and folders inside `test` folder. Actually just restarting Android Studio helped. Simple, but worked.