# App crashes when running under the Guest Login in Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-studio, illegalargumentexception, dex, multi-user

I was running the app under Guest Login and the App is crashing at launcher screen. And the app is fine under the Normal Login

I referred this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253434/android-dexclassloader-error-optimized-data-directory-not-owned-by-current) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729569/mockito-dexmaker-on-android-2) but no solution found.

**Crash Report**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo            {com.packagename.projectname/com.packagename.projectname.LancherActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Optimized data directory /storage/emulated/12/optimized is not owned by the current user. Shared storage cannot protect your application from code injection attacks.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Optimized data directory /storage/emulated/12/optimized is not owned by the current user. Shared storage cannot protect your application from code injection attacks.
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:102)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadDex(DexFile.java:151)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:265)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:223)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:109)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
        at dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.<init>(DexClassLoader.java:57)
        at DexLoader7.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at com.packagename.projectname.LauncherActivity.ʾ$3bf1605b(:753)
        at com.packagename.projectname.LauncherActivity.ʽ(:266)
        at com.packagename.projectname.LauncherActivity.onCreate(:197)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                ... 10
```

Error that caused in that line at `com.packagename.projectname.LauncherActivity.ʾ$3bf1605b(:753)` was using Google Plus Login.

```
return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(SigninActivity.this).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build()).addScope(Plus
        .SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Processes are isolated per user unless otherwise specified, you cannot access another user's data partition if its not your current user.

For instance, 0 can't access 10 and vice-versa.

Comment: Just for clarification. what if the user runs the app in Guest Login

Comment: Guest is still an actual user if I remember correctly, you can check by doing adb shell pm list users and it should have the guest user. My guess is that this app is trying to access another user's data, which is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks for your time. What do you mean by Another user data

Comment: My guess would be that GoogleApiClient is not functional with guest users.

Comment: I just run the sample of GoogleApiClient in Guest login. To my shock, it works fine.

Comment: that is really weird.. sounds like a race condition