# Attempt to mockito mock any class generates ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

When I run the following code:

```
public class ActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {
    ....
    public void testCanCreateMockito() {
        List mockedList = Mockito.mock(List.class);
    }
}
```

I get the following exceptions:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
at com.acesounderglass.hungertracker.ActivityTest.testCanCreateMockito(ActivityTest.java:60)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:238)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:70)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
... 32 more
```

This occurs with any class, List was just an easy example.  My gradle dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+"
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('libs/dexmaker-1.0.jar')
}
```

I've upgraded gradle to 1.1, tried using the experimental unit test feature and not, nothing seems to make a difference.  What's going on?

Answer (score 95):

I received this error when I was missing the two dexmaker dependencies.

Adding these lines to the app/gradle.build file is working for me.

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

I am also using Android Studio and have found it to be a good idea to restart AS after altering the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you, this help me a lot.
I attached another reference as this solution : http://www.luisdelarosa.com/2013/04/15/java-lang-exceptioninitializererror-when-using-mockito-on-android/

Comment: This works for me with `@RunWIth(AndroidJunit4.class)` but then uncovers `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator` :(

Comment: What exactly is DexMaker and what does it do?

Comment: Note that you only need to click on Sync Project with Gradle Files when you modify dependencies. You don't need to completely restart AS.

Answer (score 10):

For me this eventually worked:

```
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4"
androidTestCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this because I was using proguard for my debug builds because of the 65K method limit (Yes, I need to cut down on the number of dependencies), and that was causing this error for me.

I added this in my (debug) proguard config to solve it:

```
### Keep Mockito
-keep class org.mockito.** { *; }
-keep interface org.mockito.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.dexmaker.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.dexmaker.** { *; }
```

Not sure If I really need all four of those lines, but this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

***LOOK HERE IF YOU DON'T BUILD YOUR APKS USING GRADLE!!!!***

If you don't build your app using gradle (which, unfortunately, my team doesn't) then the above solutions may not work for you. Let me explain a little bit more about how dexmaker-mockito works before giving the solution to the issue.

**Motivation**

Mockito is a mocking framework for Java and comes packaged with cglib which creates Bytecode mocks, this is how Mockito/Junit outside of Instrumentation tests works. But if you're trying to run Mockito in Android instrumentation tests then Bytecode mocks are not sufficient and you need mocks that Mockito can load into the Dex classloader that ART/Dalvik can understand and that's where Dexmaker comes in. Dexmaker has a Mockito "plugin" that allows Mockito to dynamically switch to using it to create Dex mocks.

**How does it know to switch?**

The dexmaker-mockito jar has a top level folder named `mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a fully qualified name `com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker`. When this jar is packaged with an APK, this top level folder can be included as a "class loader resource".

The class that Mockito uses to abstract the Mocking layer is called [MockUtil](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/e4673b53d25c15bddedbc6d76c8f910340e9fe64/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/configuration/plugins/PluginLoader.java) and, statically, it determines which MockMaker subclass it should use by checking for these resources in the classloader that it is launched from via its [PluginLoader](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/e4673b53d25c15bddedbc6d76c8f910340e9fe64/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/configuration/plugins/PluginLoader.java). If the resource from dexmaker-mockito can be found, then `com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker` is instantiated and used as the MockMaker but, if it's not, Mockito defaults to using CGLib which is incompatible within Android's DVM.

**Problem**

Depending on how you build your APK, you can potentially strip that class loader resource and cause Mockito to not dynamically switch to using Dexmaker.

**Fix**

First, include the jars that dexmaker requires:  mockito 1.9.5+, junit, dexmaker-mockito 1.0+ and dexmaker 1.0+ and then simply reflectively switch which MockMaker Mockito will use manually. This is safe, given the fact that if this is running in the DVM, using the default CGLib MockMaker won't ever work since it produces Bytecode mocks.

```
static {
    try {
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        if (loader == null) {
            loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        }

        Enumeration<URL> resources = loader.getResources("mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker");
        if (resources == null || !resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            LOGGER.info("Replacing Mockito mockMaker because the classloader resources were not present.");
            Field field = MockUtil.class.getDeclaredField("mockMaker");
            Class<?> pluginClass = loader.loadClass("com.google.dexmaker.mockito.DexmakerMockMaker");
            Object plugin = pluginClass.newInstance();
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, plugin);
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("Mockito class loader resources present");
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            throw new AssertionError("Unable to replace mockMaker to be the DexmakerMockMaker", e);
        } else {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AssertionError("Unable to replace mockMaker to be the DexmakerMockMaker");
        }
    }
}
```

and be sure to add this as well because dexmaker will need to know where to output its Dex mocks.

```
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", "/sdcard/");
```

[image: mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker]

Comment: It seems fragile and generally inadvisable to work around a classpath issue in tests by intervening at the classloader level, a bit like trying to get the egg yolks out of a cake after mixing and baking. Even if you don't use Gradle, there should be an equivalent build file manipulation in your system of choice that avoids the modification here.

Comment: @Jeff Bowman It's not a classpath issue. It's a classloader resource issue...the dexmaker jars are absolutely on the classpath or this would fail every time. I'm not sure if you have a non-trivial project that doesn't utilize gradle but solving some build issues using deprecated and undocumented jars provided with the Android SDK is not fun :-)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I have a unique situation where I'm testing code across multiple class loaders this helped me to get Mockito working in a "child" class loader...

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon the same error and could make it work by using

`androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3'`

in my **build.gradle**.

I previously made the mistake to only import `'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3'`.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error with EasyMock and eventually traced it to an absence of dexmaker.  I solved it with the following dependency:

```
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
```

That might work for mockito as well

Answer (score 1):

User23's answer is close to the solution that worked for me.

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker) you have to do the following things to activate Mockito in your Android app:

1. Download [dexmaker-1.4.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/crittercism/dexmaker/dexmaker/1.4/dexmaker-1.4.jar) and [dexmaker-mockito-1.4.jar](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/content/com/crittercism/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/1.4/dexmaker-mockito-1.4.jar) and put them into your libs folder.
2. Add the following dependencies into your build.gradle:

   `androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"`
   `androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['dexmaker-1.4.jar'])`
   `androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['dexmaker-mockito-1.4.jar'])`

Comment: Extra props for linking the official docs.