# Android instrumentation tests with Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I'm trying to use Mockito framework with android instrumentation tests but I can't initialize it correctly. I have the following test class:

```
class MainKontorTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<MainActivity> {

    @Mock Dependency bar;

    @Override
    public void setUp() {
        super.setUp();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    public void testSomething() {
        Foo foo = new Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test, I get the following error and stacktrace:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
>   at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.createProxyClass(ClassImposterizer.java:95)
>   at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:57)
>   at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
>   at org.mockito.internal.creation.cglib.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
>   at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
>   at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:43)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.DefaultAnnotationEngine.process(DefaultAnnotationEngine.java:66)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:71)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:55)
>   at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:108)
>   at org.arkadiy.moduledelegationsample.ui.main.MainKontorTest.setUp(MainKontorTest.java:20)
>   at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:132)
>   at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.runProtected(AndroidTestResult.java:77)
>   at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestResult.run(AndroidTestResult.java:55)
>   at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.NonLeakyTestSuite$NonLeakyTest.run(NonLeakyTestSuite.java:63)
>   at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:243)
>   at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:238)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.DelegatingTestSuite.run(DelegatingTestSuite.java:103)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.AndroidTestSuite.run(AndroidTestSuite.java:69)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit3.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:90)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>   at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
>   at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:54)
>   at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:240)
>   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1869)
>   Caused by: org.mockito.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException-->null
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:238)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:145)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:117)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:109)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:105)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.(Enhancer.java:70)
>   ... 40 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:385)
>   at org.mockito.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:220)
>   ... 45 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:300)
>   ... 49 more

How can I use Mockito with Instrumentation tests? I have tried using Mockito with newer [Rule api](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/testing/ui-testing/espresso-testing.html#build) but the error was the same.

Comment: If you don't build your APKs using gradle, see my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290795/attempt-to-mockito-mock-any-class-generates-exceptionininitializererror/41350001#41350001 for more information

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The mocks that Mockito creates are generated class files; however, Mockito is designed for use in a JVM, so out of the box it generates `.class` files using `cglib`. Android Instrumentation test cases run on devices or emulators, so they need Dalvik `.dex` files.

You'll need to ensure you're including [DexMaker](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker) on your classpath. The [dexmaker-mockito](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.crittercism.dexmaker%22) Maven project seems to be right, though it depends on Mockito 1.10.5, which is a few versions behind at this point.

As a side note, unless you use the [Android Testing Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html), you will need to use JUnit3 semantics. You will not be able to use `@Rule` fields or custom test runners; you will also need to override `setUp` and `tearDown` (as opposed to `@Before` and `@After` annotations) and name your tests as `testFooBar` (as opposed to `@Test` annotations).

Comment: Is there an example of what annotations to use, how to define the class, test methods etc?

Comment: If you don't build your APKs using gradle, this may not work for you. See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290795/attempt-to-mockito-mock-any-class-generates-exceptionininitializererror/41350001#41350001 for more information

Comment: Why can't we use **@Rule** annotations with JUnit 4?

Comment: @Igor You can, but should be aware that Android instrumentation tests (which are a main reason people look to DexMaker as in this question) use JUnit 3 as their built-in library. JUnit 4 and it's `@Rule` are only available in JVM/Robolectric tests (not this question) or through the support library in my link above.