# Mockito mocks run actual Android code in Lollipop or greater

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, dexmaker

So I have a Database class that has a dependency that extends SQLOpenHelper and I am testing using Android instrumented tests and Mockito to mock dependencies. We are noticing that Mockito isn't actually mocking the implementations when doing `Mockito.mock(class)` instead the actual code is running and throwing null pointer exceptions as we would expect. On API 19 devices the tests run as expected and the mocks work correctly.

Does anyone have any suggestions or things to try? I've tried real devices and emulators with similar results. Could this be a Mockito issue, or a dex-maker issue? I haven't found any information while searching for it.

After some more testing any class I mock with Mockito actually just uses the implementation. Here are my dependencies

```
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2'
```

Note: This is also in a library module if that makes any difference.

Comment: Please add some example code of your tests. Also, I assume you are talking about InstrumentedUnitTests (androidTest), right?

Comment: That's correct. I'll get some sample code. But regardless of what I try to mock Mockito creates the instance but executes the actual code, but only on >=API21 and only for this project, other apps Mockito seems to work fine.

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will probably help

Comment: Just to clarify, have you tried the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267572/mockito-dexmaker-on-android)?

Comment: I did try that solution and that had no effect. I'm going to work on getting a MCVE together

Comment: @DavidRawson I am currently unable to reproduce this in a simple new project. It seems to be only in our app. I tried setting it up like it was, with a library module and the instrumented tests in there and Mockito works as expected. There's something I'm missing about this project config but nothing I'm trying is working.

Comment: It would for the upvoters to clarify if they are experiencing the same problem

Comment: Also perhaps you can add your build.gradle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So getting rid of our old Mockito dependencies and dexmaker and using the new: [Mockito-android](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.mockito%7Cmockito-android%7C2.6.1%7Cjar)

Fixed our issues